Rearranging exponentially distributed random variables by size
Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be i.i.d. random variables, exponentially distributed with parameter 1. We rearrange the variables in a nondecreasing order, i.e. we find indices $i_1,\ldots, i_n$ such that $X_{i_1}\leq X_{i_2}\leq\ldots\leq X_{i_n}$ (so $X_{i_1}$ is equal to the minimum and $X_{i_n}$ to the maximum of the random variables)

Prove: The coordinates of the random vector $(X_{i_1}, X_{i_2} - X_{i_1},\ldots,X_{i_n} - X_{i_{n-1}})$ are independent and exponentially distributed with parameters $(n,n-1,\ldots,1)$.

I was able to prove that the minimum $X_{i_1}$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $n$ but I'm not sure how to proceed with the other coordinates, and I don't know how to prove that they are independent.

There is an elegant proof using thinning/merging of Poisson processes (and exponential racing that stems from those concepts), but I am not sure if OP is aware of this concept. So, let me tackle this problem using more elementary approach.

Write $[n] = \{1, \ldots, n\}$ for simplicity, and define the random variable $I$ by
$$ I = \underset{i \in [n]}{\arg\min} \, X_i, $$
the index for which $X_i$ is minimized. Since $X_i$'s are i.i.d. continuous random variables, $I$ is well-defined with probability one.
Now we claim:

Claim. Let $I$ be as above, and write $X'_j = X_j - X_I$ and $ \mathcal{J} = [n] \setminus \{I\}$ for simplicity. Then

$X_I$, $I$, and $(X'_j)_{j\in\mathcal{J}}$ are mutually independent.
$X_I$ has $\text{Exp}(n)$ distribution.
$I$ is uniformly distributed on $[n]$.
$(X'_j)_{j\in\mathcal{J}}$ is a family of i.i.d. having $\text{Exp}(1)$ distributions.


Once this has been proved, OP's problem is almost immediately solved by induction on $n$.
So, let us prove the claim. Let $x \geq 0$ and $x_2, \ldots, x_n \geq 0$. Then
\begin{align*}
&\mathbf{P}( X_I > x \color{blue}{\texttt{ and }} I = 1 \color{blue}{\texttt{ and }} X'_j > x_j \text{ for all } j \in \mathcal{J} ) \\
&= \mathbf{P}( X_1 > x \color{blue}{\texttt{ and }} I = 1 \color{blue}{\texttt{ and }} X_j - X_1 > x_j \text{ for all } j = 2, \ldots, n ) \\
&= \mathbf{P}( X_1 > x \color{blue}{\texttt{ and }} X_j - X_1 > x_j \text{ for all } j = 2, \ldots, n ),
\end{align*}
where the last line follows by noting that the condition $I = 1$ is automatically implied by the inequalities $X_j - X_1 > x_j$ for $j = 2, \ldots, n$. Now, since $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are independent, the probability in the last line is computed as
\begin{align*}
&= \int_{x}^{\infty} \mathbf{P}( X_j - X_1 > x_j \text{ for all } j = 2, \ldots, n \mid X_1 = t) f_{X_1}(t) \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \int_{x}^{\infty} \left[ \prod_{j=2}^{n} \mathbf{P}( X_j > t + x_j) \right] f_{X_1}(t) \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \int_{x}^{\infty} \left[ \prod_{j=2}^{n} e^{-(t + x_j)} \right] e^{-t} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \frac{1}{n} e^{-nx} \prod_{j=2}^{n} e^{-x_j}. \tag{1}\label{e:1}
\end{align*}
This computation is essentially all we need. First, plugging $x_2 = \ldots = x_n = 0$ to $\eqref{e:1}$, we get
$$ \mathbf{P}( X_I > x \color{blue}{\texttt{ and }} I = 1) = \frac{1}{n} e^{-nx}. \tag{2}\label{e:2} $$
By the same argument (or by appealing to the exchangeability), we also have
$$ \mathbf{P}( X_I > x \color{blue}{\texttt{ and }} I = i) = \frac{1}{n} e^{-nx} \tag{3}\label{e:3} $$
for all $x \geq 0$ and $i \in [n]$, showing that $X_I$ and $I$ are independent, with $X_I \sim \text{Exp}(n)$ and $I$ uniformly distributed over $[n]$. Moreover, dividing $\eqref{e:1}$ by $\eqref{e:2}$ gives
$$ \mathbf{P}( X'_j > x_j \text{ for all } j \in \mathcal{J} \mid X_I > x \color{blue}{\texttt{ and }} I = 1 )
= \prod_{j=2}^{n} e^{-x_j}, $$
proving that $(X'_j)_{j\in\mathcal{J}}$ are independent $\text{Exp}(1)$ variables given $X_I$ and $\{I = 1\}$. Then, either by invoking the same argument or exchangeability, the same claim holds true with $\{ I = 1 \}$ replaced by $\{ I = i \}$ for any $i \in [n]$, and therefore the desired assertion follows. $\square$

Let $X_1,\dotsc, X_n$ be i.i.d exponetial random variables with rate $1$ and let $X\sim \text{Exp}(1)$.  Define the random variables
$$
Y_{i} = X_{(i)} - X_{(i-1)} \quad (1\leq i \leq n)
$$
where $X_{(i)}$ is the $i$th order statistic. The joint density of the order statistics is given by
$$
f_{X_{(1)},\dotsc,X_{(n)}}(x_1,\dotsc,x_n) = n!f_{X_1,\dotsc,X_n}(x_1,\dotsc,x_n) =n!\prod_{i=1}^Nf_{X}(x_i)\quad (x_1<x_2\dotsc<x_n)
$$
where in the final step we used the fact that $X_i$ are i.i.d with common distribution $X$.
Therefore the change of variables formula implies that
$$
\begin{align}
f_{\mathbf{Y}}(\mathbf{y})&=f_{\mathbf{X}}(y_1,y_1+y_2,\dotsc,y_1+y_2+\dotsc.y_{n-1})\\
&=n!\times \exp{(-[ny_1+(n-1)y_2+\dotsb+y_{n-1}]})\\
&=\prod_{i=1}^n (n-i+1)\times \exp(-(n-i+1)\times y_{i})
\end{align}
$$
implying that $Y_{i}$ are independent with rate $n-i+1$ for $i=1,\dotsc,n$ as desired.
